# Ruby on Rails Form POSTed data cannot be viewed by show function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby and Ror
I am reading [Rails Guides Getting Started](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).
I am stuck in the section
5.6 Saving Data in the Controller.

I see a NoMethodError in Posts#show Error in my browser after submitting the form.
I have coded the required view file show.html.erb.
What mistake I do?

Wasn't the POST parameters title and the text stored in the @post instance variable once I defined the create function in PostsController?

Is this the problem?
How can I overcome this?

How can i view the form posted data after i saved in db in this scenery?

PostsController:

```
    class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  end

  private
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
    end

    def show
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

show.html.erb:

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @post.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Text:</strong>
  <%= @post.text %>
</p>
```

Comment: Can you show your `PostsController` and the `show.html.erb`?

Comment: of course i am doing in a sec.

Comment: I think I have an answer for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined `show` as a `private` method, this makes `show` invisible outside of `PostsController`.  Update your controller code moving `show` method outside `private:`, to make it public.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
    end
end
```

Comment: thanks it works. How can one define new methods after a private method in a class in Ruby, as a linguistic question this time.

Comment: Similar to how you've defined private, you just need to use `public` instead of `private`, but public being default why not just arrange all public methods before private or protected methods.

Comment: sorry maybe I've  marked the wrong answer as answer wrt to time.time notifiers and vertical position on the screen was a bit confusing, i am not sure. and @vee i ve understood the private and publics, thanks.

Comment: @FSC, I think you did alright :).  You can order the answer by their time by clicking the "Oldest" tab at the top.

Comment: I've just meant i might not have determined correctly which answerer was first to give correct answer. thanks at all.

Answer (score 2):

Your `show` method in the `PostsController` needs to be public:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
   @post = Post.new(post_params)

   @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  end

  def show
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

you have added show action inside private block .put that before private